# How do i install python modules without cmd?

Tags: python, module

I am a student in a high school (UK), I am trying to use Colorama in a school python assessment but for some reason its either not installed properly or ANSICON isn't installed properly and so I cant do my work, for obvious reasons CMD has been disabled for each student account.

So is there anyway i can install python modules without CMD?

Side note:
python imports Colorama and runs and prints my desired text but without the colour. Here is my code and the output ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaC3E.jpg)), the code is linked.

```
import colorama
from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style

init(convert=True)

print (Fore.RED+"Red")]
```

Comment: This is probably a question for you teacher, is it an essential requirement to have colours in your script?

Comment: The module is installed; if it wasn't, you would get an ImportError here.

Comment: did you try using batch files

Comment: in the assessment criteria additional items (for appearance) are worth extra marks so yes i would say its a requirement, the import error isnt there however colorama doesnt work? And im not really sure how to use batch files so nope i have not

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me in terminal with `convert=False` but not in idle.
Probably idle doesn't support colors.
So the problem is not in program, but in idle text output.